# httperf repeat wsesslog

Tags: linux, web-server, load-testing

For httperf with a wsesslog is there a way to repeat the activity in the script without wrapping it in a shell loop?

If I do `httperf  --server=test.foo.com --wsesslog=20,0,foo.wsesslog` I get 20 sessions that run through the script in the file.  Is there a way I can have 20 sessions that run through the script X times?

Comment: `--num-calls` seems to be ignored...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comment: [The source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#8mz6y1Nxpew/trunk/httperf/src/httperf.c&q=num-calls%20package:http://httperf%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=1072) says that the first argument of `--wsesslog` overrides `--num-calls`. That makes sense. I'm not seeing the wsesslog generator source making any reference to the --num-calls parameter.

I don't see the program doing what you're looking for without modifications. The wsesslog generator [exits when the number of session is generates is equal or greater to the first parameter of the wsesslog argument](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#8mz6y1Nxpew/trunk/httperf/src/gen/wsesslog.c&q=wsesslog&exact_package=http://httperf.googlecode.com/svn&d=3&l=190) (with the exit signaled through a global variable... ewww!).

You're best off just wrapping it in a shell. While, in theory, you could probably hack a parameter onto the wsesslog argument and just [execute core_loop() that many times](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#8mz6y1Nxpew/trunk/httperf/src/httperf.c&q=core_loop&exact_package=http://httperf.googlecode.com/svn&l=1135). The core_loop() function isn't idempotent, though, so it's probably not that simple.

Comment: "No" doesn't get more thorough than this :-)